# How do I translate the definition of the mathematical term "Latinity" into Chinese?

Tags: translation, terminology

I'm going to try giving another mathematics talk in Chinese.  I'm struggling with this sentence:

> Definition: The **Latinity** lambda(G) of a graph G is the smallest d for which there exists a d-dimensional PLH with PLH graph isomorphic to G.

("Latinity" is a mathematical term which I coined as part of my research.)

These are my attempts:

> 定义：图G的**拉丁度**lambda(G)是存在具有d维PLH图和G同构最小的d。
>
> 定义：图G的**拉丁度**lambda(G)是最小的d，这样存在d维PLH其中和G同构的PLH图。

They seem very clunky.  My main problem is that "for which" doesn't seem to naturally translate into Chinese.

**Question**: How do I translate the definition of "Latinity" into Chinese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

定义：图G的拉丁度lambda(G) = d，
d是使与G同构的d维PLH图存在的最小值。